# Problematic For Loops: Repeatedly Printing Lines That Contains Key Phrases From Files in a Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm trying to write a script to scan for key phrases from every file in my root directory, and print out the lines from these files that contains the key phrases. Currently my script is able to scan through all the files in my directory and print out the lines containing the key phrases, but it would print it about 70 times when it only exists once in these files. For example if there was **ONE LINE** in the entire directory, it would print out that one specific line like 70 times. I suspect there is something wrong with my for loops, but I was not able to debug the problem. I hope to make my script only print these lines for the amount of times they actually appear in the file. I'm quite new to Python, please help! Thanks!

```
import os

path = "D:\\MyFolder\\" #The root directory I hope to scan all the files from

important = [] #The array for storing the lines with the key phrases
key_phrases = ["testing example1", "testing example2"] #If the lines contain these key phrases, it should be stored into the important array and printed in the end


for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(path): 
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt') or f.endswith('.log')] #The follow 3 lines are to make the file openable
    files.sort() # file is sorted list

    files = [os.path.join(path, name) for name in files]

    for filename in files:

            with open(filename) as f:
                f = f.readlines()

            for line in f:
                for phrase in key_phrases: 
                    if phrase in line:
                        important.append(line)
                        break

            print(important)
```

Comment: I've edited out the raw string so that the syntax highlighting works on this site, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Don't `print(important)` for every file. Print it after the loops are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, it worked!